# Check how long the current user has been logged into

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

**Background:**

I have a requirement where I need to allow the refresh token live for a really long time for some types of user, but I want to limit it (expire it) for other users.

Both sets of users have to be in the same Cognito user-pool.

My first thought was to check how long the users have been logged-in if they are the type of user I want to limit and call global sign-out to force those users to re-authenticate, but I cannot find any API that will tell me how long a user has been logged in.

As an important side note, since I am using Cognito with Amplify + Appsync, the refresh token is used to obtain new session tokens until the refresh token expires.

**Question:**

Is there a way in Amplify or Cognito APIs to find out how a user has been logged in in that particular device?

Comment: Is it possible to use 2 different app clients? One with long refresh token and one with a shorter duration?

Comment: We need to use a single identity pool, which only takes a single user pool client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito has a feature that remembers the user's device and records the date in which the device was last authenticated.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-device-tracking.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetDevice.html

Comment: This works, thank you!